# Error en Angular: earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: eqfeed_callback is not defined at earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1:1

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, google-maps, angular13

Estoy intentando replicar el ejemplo de **Importing Data into Maps** ([Importing Data into Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data#maps_earthquake_markers-typescript)) a mi proyecto de angular pero me aparece el siguiente error en consola:

```
earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: eqfeed_callback is not defined
    at earthquake_GeoJSONP.js:1:1
```

##### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'map';

  ngOnInit() {

    let map: google.maps.Map;
    
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
    });
    
    loader.load().then(() => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
        mapTypeId: "terrain",
      });

      // map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');

      // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
      const script = document.createElement("script");

      // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
      // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
      script.src =
        "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

      const eqfeed_callback = function (results: any) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          const coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);
      
          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
          });
          // place marker in map
          marker.setMap(map)
        }
      };    
    });   
  }
}
```

##### app.component.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

##### app.component.css

```
 #map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

##### Paquetes Instalados

Este es el paquete de googlemaps que instalé en mi proyecto.

```
npm install @googlemaps/js-api-loader

npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

##### Versión de mi Angular

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: win32 x64
```

##### Lo que muestra mi código

[image: Lo que me aparece]

##### Lo que espero que aparezca

Según la documentación de Google Maps en el siguiente enlace: [Importing Data into Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data#maps_earthquake_markers-typescript)
[image: Lo que espero que aparezca]

De ante mano les agradezco por el tiempo y el apoyo.